# Remove duplicate in array based on column value

Tags: php, arrays

I need some help with this. I have the following array:

```
$result = array(
    0 => array('a'=>1,'b'=>'data1'),
    1 => array('a'=>2,'b'=>'data2'),
    2 => array('a'=>1,'b'=>'data3'),
);
```

I want to remove duplicate rows by comparing the values of column 'a'. The expected output should be:

```
array(
    0 => array('a'=>1,'b'=>'data1'),
    1 => array('a'=>2,'b'=>'data2'),
);
```

Or:

```
array(
    1 => array('a'=>2,'b'=>'data2'),
    2 => array('a'=>1,'b'=>'data3'),
);
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Newer canonical with a battery of effective techniques: [Filter/Remove rows where column value is found more than once in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45603614/2943403)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a small array of all possible values of field `a` using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map), grab all unique values from it with [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) and then intersect it with the original array using [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key).

```
$output = array_intersect_key(
    $result, 
    array_unique(array_map(function($item) {
        return $item['a'];
    }, $result))
);
```

Or, since 5.5:

```
$output = array_intersect_key($result, array_unique(array_column($result, 'a')));
```