# removing duplicate from 2D array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, duplicates

I have an array which is 2D and I want to remove duplicates from it,

the var dump look like this `1=>abc.com. 2=>acc.com, 3=>abc.com` so I want to remove the second occurence of abc.com, that is I want to remove `3=>abc.com`,

I tried to use the nested loop, but the code is not working.

```
 foreach ($var as $m)
   {
        foreach ($var as $s)
        {
                if(isset($m['Email'])){
                    if($m['Email'] == $s['Email']){
                    echo 'matched with '.$s['Email'];
                    echo '</br>';
                    unset($s);
                    //echo $v['Email'];
                    //echo "<br>";
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the [array_unique function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Edit: Here is the code and output from [Here (Codepad)](http://codepad.org/wbskZV8H)

**PHP**

```
<?php
$input = array("1" => "abc.com", "2" => "acc.com", "3" => "abc.com");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => abc.com
    [2] => acc.com
)
```

Edit2: To have it remove duplicates from a specific column, just use

```
$output = array_intersect_key($input, array_unique(array_column($input, 'Email')));
```

Where $input is the complete array and 'Email' is the column you wish to remove duplicates from

Comment: I just pasted a small snippet of my array, Actually my array consists of more than this, like Email, Id, contact number, etc, I just want to check duplicate on email, so I cant use this function

Comment: Then you are looking for something that is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219362/remove-duplicate-in-array-based-on-column-value

Comment: Your code will just be: $output = array_intersect_key($input, array_unique(array_column($input, 'Email')));

Comment: thanks, it says call to undefined function, what is $item and $result in other example?

Answer (score 1):

array_unique($array);

you also have a mistake in your nested foreach. Assuming what you posted above, you only need one foreach loop. If you need to add a 2nd, it should be based on the temp variables you are setting e.g. foreach($table as $row => $key)  .. you can do foreach($key as $item)

etc!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to remove the duplicates you can use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php),

```
$arr = array(
    1 => "abc.com", 
    2 => "acc.com", 
    3 => "abc.com"
); 

$result = array_unique($arr);
print_r($result);
```